# Meteor: how can I load an external script on the server side?

Tags: meteor, stripe-payments

On the client side, I can easily load an external scripts using the following in my template header:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>
</head>
```

However, the same method can't be used to load an external script on the server side.

I need to load this external library because when I install the ["Stripe-meteor"](https://github.com/tyler-johnson/stripe-meteor) package, I get errors. With Stripe, a part of the payment is achieved on the client side and an other part on the server side...

Should I:

- download the javascript code and save it on my project directory?
- try to install the package?
- use npm to download some packages?
- use some built-in functions of meteor to load the script?
- any other idea?

What's your recommendation? What's the best practice?

Answer (score 2):

Install the Stripe Meteor package - the scripts you'll need from Stripe are included in that package.

Comment: Which package? If you talk about stripe-meteor, I tried but it didn't work, I got a bunch of errors. For instance I got the message: cannot find function StripeAPI .

Comment: Yes, [stripe-meteor](https://github.com/tyler-johnson/stripe-meteor). I would try re-working through the steps from the install section first. But if you are still getting errors, consider posting a new question with as much detail about the errors as possible.